# How to tell where an element is located on the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a few hundred elements within a listview, and I want to know which elements are on the screen and at what position. If I do a `Canvas.getLeft()` it simply returns zero. I want to be able to transform the item closest to the middle of the screen so that it's bigger than the others.

Comment: When you say "on the screen," do you mean their position relative to the (0,0) coordinate of your window, or relative to the entire OS visible area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to get the position of your element relative to your `Window`, you could do the following:

```
Point relativePos = yourElement
    .TransformToAncestor(yourWindow)
    .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

`yourWindow` can be replaced with any parent visual that contains `yourElement` - if, for example, you wanted the position relative to the `ListView`, you could replace it with `yourListView`, etc.

Comment: you're a life saver. Such a simple answer to my solution too. I'd upvote you but I don't have 15 reputation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the screen coordinates of the top-left point of a `ListViewItem` (or any `Visual`), you can just use the method ***[Visual.PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx)*** and pass in an empty Point:

```
var pointInScreen = yourListViewItem.PointToScreen(new Point());
```